# How to get date of today with special format?

Tags: c#, datetime

i want to have today date with this format:

```
Wednesday, May 27, 2015
```

i want to use this code:

```
richTextBox2.AppendText("\n" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + ", " +
                         DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
```

but i cant load Wednesday and may value.
How can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: thisDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"); Try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `DateTime` value, you can present that value to the end-user in nearly any way you'd like to, by applying an appropriate [display format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to it.

This will display the full names of the day and month, which seems to be what you're asking for:

```
richTextBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"));
```

Output:

> Wednesday, May 27, 2015

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting `DateTime` properties, using [custom date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) with an *english-based* culture (eg: [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.110.aspx)) would be better;

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

And `May` can be tricky here :-p.

It is not clear you try to get [full month name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [abbreviated month name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you wanna use abbreviated one, you need to change your `MMMM` specifier to [`MMM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#MMM_Specifier).